# Sum six unique digits to make 20

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction

You have 6 boxes. You can use the digits from 1 to 9 but not 0. Digit repetition is not allowed. The total sum of the numbers/digits should be 20.

$$
\huge\square\square\square\\
\huge\square\square\square
$$

Answer (score 10):

It's not possible. The sum of the 6 smallest digits (1 through 6) is 21, already greater than 20.

Comment: So, are we allowed to use negative numbers to solve this?

Comment: The question is yours, how am I supposed to know. Haha.

Comment: Yeah, it is my question but can we use negative numbers to solve this according to mathematics rules? Is that possible?

Comment: Digits are not negative or positive, I am not sure I understand you.

Comment: Alright, I got you.

Comment: @MehmoodAli if negatives are allowed I propose: `2+3-5+4+7+9`

Answer (score 9):

Seems pretty easy to me.

$$
\huge[9][1][8]\\
\huge[2]\square\square
$$

The rules don't say I need to fill in *all* of the boxes.

Answer (score 3):

If we add the [lateral-thinking](/questions/tagged/lateral-thinking) tag, I have a solution:

Write `4`, `5`, and `8` in the first three boxes
Cut off three of your fingers (also called "digits") and place one in each of the other three boxes.
Now you have 6 digits (three numbers, three fingers) in the boxes
Each finger has a value of `1` so the sum is $1+1+1+4+5+8=20$

Alternatively, if fingers have a value of `0`, then us the numbers `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, `6` and only cut off one finger (value of `0`). Now the sum is $0+2+3+4+5+6=20$

Comment: That's pretty bloody. I'd rather skip the puzzle than lose three fingers.

Answer (score 3):

Inspired by [@AlbertRenshaw's post](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/23795/4421):

Use hexadecimal.  Then $2 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 = 20_{16}\;(=32_{10})$.

This can actually work with any base from 11 to 19:

$1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 7 = 20_{11}\;(=22_{10})$
$1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 9 = 20_{12}\;(=24_{10})$
$1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 7 + 9 = 20_{13}\;(=26_{10})$
$1 + 2 + 3 + 6 + 7 + 9 = 20_{14}\;(=28_{10})$
$1 + 2 + 3 + 7 + 8 + 9 = 20_{15}\;(=30_{10})$
$1 + 4 + 5 + 7 + 8 + 9 = 20_{17}\;(=34_{10})$
$1 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 = 20_{18}\;(=36_{10})$
$3 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 = 20_{19}\;(=38_{10})$

Answer (score 1):

## 1,2,3,4,5,7

And the puzzle is in base 9.

Comment: Alas, if the puzzle were in base 9, 9 would not be a valid digit.

Comment: @IanMacDonald 9 = ∞ in base 9. xD

Comment: That's not quite how math works. :P